How do I define a diffeomorphism from $(S^3 \times \mathbb{C}) / S^1$ to $L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}$?
For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have a principal $S^1$-bundle:  ,
$$H_n : S^{2n+1} \to \mathbb{CP}^n, \quad H_n(z_0, \ldots, z_n) = [z_0 : \ldots : z_n]$$
Consider
$$H : S^3 \to S^2, \quad H(x, y, z, t) = (x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - t^2, \; 2(yz - tx), \; 2(ty + zx)).$$
On $S^3$ we consider the action of $S^1$ given by
$$(x, y, z, t) \cdot (a,b) = (ax - by, \; ay + bx, \; az - bt, \; at + bz).$$
It can be proven that $H : S^3 \to S^2$ is a principal $S^1$-bundle, that there exists a diffeomorphism $\Psi : S^2 \cong \mathbb{CP}^1$ making the diagram involving $H$ and $H_1$ commutative  and that considering the action of $S^1$ on $S^3 \times \mathbb{C}$ given by
$$(p,z) \cdot \lambda = (p \cdot \lambda, \lambda z) \quad \text{for } (p,z) \in S^3 \times \mathbb{C}, \lambda \in S^1.$$, $(S^3 \times \mathbb{C}) / S^1$ is smooth.
I am trying to prove that $(S^3 \times \mathbb{C}) / S^1$ is diffeomorphic to $L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}$, the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^1$.
I joined forces with a friend and we came up with this
My try
To prove that the quotient $(S^3 \times \mathbb{C}) / S^1$ is diffeomorphic to the tautological line bundle $L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}$, we define a map
$$
\Phi: (S^3 \times \mathbb{C}) / S^1 \to L_{\mathbb{CP}^1},
$$
where a point in $(S^3 \times \mathbb{C}) / S^1$ is represented by an equivalence class $[(p, z)]$, with $p = (z_0, z_1) \in S^3$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$. The map $\Phi$ is defined by
$$
\Phi([(p, z)]) = (z, H_1(p)),
$$
where $H_1: S^3 \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ is the Hopf fibration given by $H_1(z_0, z_1) = [z_0 : z_1]$.
To verify that $\Phi$ is well-defined, consider the equivalence relation $(p, z) \sim (p \cdot \lambda, \lambda z)$ for $\lambda \in S^1$. If $(p, z) \sim (p', z')$, then $p' = p \cdot \lambda$ and $z' = \lambda z$ for some $\lambda \in S^1$. Applying $\Phi$ to both representatives, we compute
$$
\Phi([(p', z')]) = (\lambda z, H_1(p \cdot \lambda)).
$$
Since the Hopf map is invariant under the $S^1$-action, $H_1(p \cdot \lambda) = H_1(p)$, so
$$
\Phi([(p', z')]) = (\lambda z, H_1(p)).
$$
In $L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}$, $z$ and $\lambda z$ represent the same point in the fiber over $H_1(p)$, ensuring that $\Phi([(p', z')]) = \Phi([(p, z)])$. Thus, $\Phi$ is well-defined.
To show that $\Phi$ is smooth, note that the projection $H_1: S^3 \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ is smooth and the $S^1$-action on $S^3 \times \mathbb{C}$ is smooth. The quotient $(S^3 \times \mathbb{C}) / S^1$ inherits a smooth structure, and $\Phi$ is smooth as it arises from smooth operations on the equivalence classes.
To check injectivity, suppose $\Phi([(p, z)]) = \Phi([(p', z')])$. Then $(z, H_1(p)) = (z', H_1(p'))$, implying $z = z'$ and $H_1(p) = H_1(p')$. Since $H_1(p) = H_1(p')$, there exists $\lambda \in S^1$ such that $p' = p \cdot \lambda$. From $z = z'$, we also have $z' = \lambda z$, so $(p, z) \sim (p', z')$. Thus, $\Phi$ is injective.
For surjectivity, let $(z, [z_0 : z_1]) \in L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}$. Choose any representative $(z_0, z_1) \in S^3$ such that $[z_0 : z_1] = H_1(z_0, z_1)$. Then $[(p, z)] \in (S^3 \times \mathbb{C}) / S^1$ maps to $(z, H_1(p))$ under $\Phi$, showing that $\Phi$ is surjective.
Since $\Phi$ is a smooth bijection between smooth manifolds of the same dimension, it is a diffeomorphism. Therefore, we conclude that
$$
(S^3 \times \mathbb{C}) / S^1 \cong L_{\mathbb{CP}^1}.
$$
Nevertheless, I  suspect the map is still ill-defined on z values. If that is the case, how should I define the map? Would there be anything else to correct?
Another candidate I think could be $
\Phi([(p, z)]) = (z\cdot p, H_1(p)),
$ but how to see that it is well/defined?
